# reverse a set of number using php

Tags: php

i want to display 1345 as an array
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5

i am thinking about using a for loop, but what i have does nothing. Please help

```
$a = 1345;
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
 {
echo $a%10 . "<br>";
 }
```

Comment: So what's $a when it's at home?

Comment: What do you want? To display a string as an array or make a string an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id convert it to a string and do [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: `$str = 1345; $array = str_split($str); print_r($array);` brilliant

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var_dump(array(1, 3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using var_dump() ?

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
ob_start();
var_dump($a);
$result = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1,3,4,5);
foreach($a as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

You keep changing your question, `str_split()` is the answer to the current question.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array(1,3,4,5));
```

Just this man